# Unknown entity on hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, orm

I got this error when executing the main class. Am trying to insert new record at the table portfolio. As you see am using Hibernate ORM model to do that. Also it is good to say that hibernate doing the connection to the database without any problem !

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.nortal.vspa.model.Portfolio
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1129)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1402)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:748)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:744)
at com.nortal.vspa.main.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="portfolio")
public class Portfolio implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1136208004146721604L;

@Id
@Column(name="symbol")
private String symbol;

public String getSymbol()
{
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol)
{
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
    Portfolio portfolio = new Portfolio();

    portfolio.setSymbol("MB");

    session.save(portfolio);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}

}
```

Comment: Have you listed that class in your hibernate configuration?

Comment: Is this the only entity in the application?  Have you successfully persisted other entities?

Comment: @DavidWallace you mean to list them at persistence.xml ?

Comment: @kmb385 nope. there are another entities. I don't try them yet !

Comment: I recommend reading section 1.2 of http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanx for recommendation I will read when have a time. But I need urgent solution if any !

Comment: So you expect me to cut and paste the solution from that page, because you don't have time to click a link?

Comment: @DavidWallace no :) . I don't mind to read it. but every thing must be done on time. And I print that page to read it with a cup of tea ! Thanx again .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Hibernate configuration file must list the entity classes:

```
<mapping class="com.foo.bar.Portfolio"/>
```

Or you must explicitely add the class to the configuration using

```
configuration.addClass(com.foo.bar.Portfolio.class)
```

Comment: Does the order of the mapping class configurations matter? I have the mapping class listed in the configuration file, still the exception is coming.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of incorrect dialect name.
In my case I have added server version number along with the MySQL dialect. ex.
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect