# Need to call StoredProcedure in jave using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Just want to call Stored procedure of SQL server from java using Hibernate as ORM.

The stored Procedure has so many result set which I am keeping it in Java as DTO's and each one as list in one DTO to send as JSON payload for Front-end integration.

But I am getting exception saying"org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.test.plans.dto.TemplatesDTO"

```
 public ItemDetailsDTO getItemDetails(int no) {
     Session session = getSession();
     Connection connection = null;
     List<ItemDetailsDTO> resultList  = new ArrayList<>();
     try {
            ResultSet rs = null;
            SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
            connection = sessionImpl.connection();
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("exec usp_GetItemDetails :no")
                         .addEntity(TemplatesDTO.class)
                         .setParameter("no", no);
            resultList = query.list();
     } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return resultList.get(0);
}
```

DTO :

```
import java.util.List;


public class ItemDetailsDTO {

    private List<TemplatesDTO> templates;


    public List<TemplatesDTO> gettemplates() {
        return templates;
    }
    public void settemplates(List<TemplatesDTO> templates) {
        this.templates = templates;
    }
}
```

Please find below complete trace of exception

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.test.plans.dto.TemplatesDTO
>                   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:783)
>                   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:358)
>                   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:411)
>                   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:378)
>                   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:180)
>                   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.(SQLCustomQuery.java:71)
>                   at org.hibernate.engine.query.internal.NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.createQueryPlan(NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.java:70)
>                   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:210)
>                   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:306)
>                   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
>                   at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
>                   at nbcu.compass.contingencyplans.dao.impl.ContDAOImpl.getItemDetails(ContingencyDAOImpl.java:503)
>                   at nbcu.compass.contingencyplans.dao.impl.ContDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2b97106.invoke()
>                   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>                   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
>                   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>                   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>                   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>                   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>                   at com.test.plans.dao.impl.ContDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1741e1f.getItemDetails()
>                   at com.test.plans.service.impl.ContPlanServiceImpl.getConditionScheduleItemDetails(ContingencyPlanServiceImpl.java:316)
>                   at test.plans.plans.rest.impl.PlanResourceImpl.getItemDetails(PlanResourceImpl.java:87)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>                   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>                   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)

Comment: Where is the code for `TemplatesDTO`? It seems like you did not do the mapping for it

Comment: I think alreay solution was given in this page   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667986/unknown-entity-on-hibernate